# to get a data from html in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a html DOM. I want to get the phone data from the onclick attribute. Here is the html DOM

```
<div class="data">
  <a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>

  <a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 733-2044&amp;doctorID=2013072910215251990870&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>
</div>
```

What i have tried to get the phone number like (205) 324-5322 and (205) 733-2044.

jQuery:

```
var fra = jQuery('.review-column-b strong a').attr( 'onclick' );
console.log(fra);
```

After i dont have knowledge to retrive the phone number from the string. please help me,

Thank you,

Thank you again. I am going to edit my question

Thank you. But i have a doubt here, If i have a HTML DOM like

```
    <div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>
</div><div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-6577&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a></div>
```

now, how can i appendTO each phone number to "data" div ? Because i want to display the respective phone number in the respective div.

Comment: could you pleas share a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Can you show us the popup window function?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have the popup function. Only i have html DOM.

Comment: I think you are addressing the wrong issue here (It's possible to get the number form your `onclick` attribute, but it's a horrible 'solution'.) Are you able to change your markup?

Comment: the query `.review-column-b strong a` has selectors in it which are not available in your example code - therefor nothing matches

Comment: do you have the access to change the html? if you have you can move the variable of popupwindow() to the href.

Comment: birdspider, Thanks for comment. But i gave the html dom here. I think you can use the current selector.

Comment: I want to just get the phone number from the html DOM. I dont want to use any function to do any javascript magic.

Comment: @user3747821, do you mind if you provide information asked by others? All are here to help you.

Comment: @user3747821 i cant see how you are going to achieve what you want without javascript/jquery magic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with regex:

```
 var number = $('a').attr('onclick').match(/phone\=([0-9\(\) -]+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this:

```
var link = $('a').attr('onclick');
var equalPosition = link.indexOf('=');
var number = link.substring(equalPosition + 1);
var call=number.split('&')[0];
```

jsFiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/2c2sjsa1/)

Comment: Thank you. But i have a doubt here, If i have a HTML DOM like <div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a>
</div><div class="data">
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow('/includes/phoneNumberLookup.cfm?phone=(205) 324-5322&amp;doctorID=2013072910215350207237&amp;url= ' + document.URL + ' &amp;refUrl=','',250,150); return false;">  Click to See Phone Number</a></div> how can i appendTO each 'data'